# how to create different data id for text box which is getting on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want  add text-boxes on each click that work well but i need add id for each text-boxes which is added dynamical. i am struggling to give  id for it below i give the code used for adding textbox on click

```js
$(function() {
  $('.plusicon').on('click', function() {
    var textBox = '<input type="text" class="textbox"/>';
    var a = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#' + a + "box").append(textBox);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="plusicondiv" class="plusicon" src="vectorimages/pluseicon.svg" />//for clickbutton//
<div id="plusicondivbox" class="insidediv " style="margin-top:-53px;"></div>//div for adding txtbox//
```

Comment: What should be the value for `id` attribute ?

Comment: `$(textBox).attr('id', YOUR_ID)` should work!

Comment: actually i have more textbox if i click multipletime. i need diffrent id for each textbox how i give it

Comment: Have a global variable, assign it after `click` and `increment` it... Next time, text-box will have new value..

Comment: can you please give the syntax becouse i don't get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a `global-variable` and `increment` it after every `click-event`

```js
$(function() {
  var count = 0;
  $('.plusicon').on('click', function() {
    var textBox = '<input type="text" class="textbox"/>';
    var a = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#' + a + "box").append(textBox);
    $('#' + a + "box input:last").attr('id', 'id_' + count);
    ++count;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="plusicondiv" class="plusicon" src="vectorimages/pluseicon.svg" />
<br/>
<div id="plusicondivbox" class="insidediv"></div>
```

***Or*** assign inline attribute by concatenation:

```js
$(function() {
  var count = 0;
  $('.plusicon').on('click', function() {
    var textBox = '<input type="text" id="id_' + count + '" class="textbox"/>';
    var a = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#' + a + "box").append(textBox);
    ++count;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="plusicondiv" class="plusicon" src="vectorimages/pluseicon.svg" />
<br/>
<div id="plusicondivbox" class="insidediv"></div>
```

Comment: don't forget that if you are using the textboxes for a form - you will need a name attribute for each - (unless you are getting the value via javascript / submitting via AJAX) otherwise they will not be in the submitted form data.

Answer (score 0):

Use instead of `$(this)` `$(textbox)`

```
$(function () {
 $('.plusicon').on('click', function () {


    var textBox = '<input type="text" class="textbox"/>';
    var a = $(textBox).attr("id","your_id");

    $('#'+a+"box").append(textBox);


   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at below code. We can define global counter which will get incremented each time you press plus button so that you will get unique number each time. that number we can use to define unique textbox id as follows:

```js
var textBoxCounter = 1;
$(function() {
  $('.plusicon').on('click', function() {


    var textBox = '<input type="text" class="textbox"/>';
    textBox = $(textBox);
    textBox.attr("id", "myTextBox_" + textBoxCounter);
    textBoxCounter++;
    var a = $(this).attr("id");

    $('#' + a + "box").append(textBox);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="plusicondiv" class="plusicon" src="vectorimages/pluseicon.svg" />


<div id="plusicondivbox" class="insidediv " style="margin-top:53px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you ,use global variable which will give dynamicid for your textboxes ie(different id for dynamic textboxes):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </script>
    <script>
        var idCount=0;
        $(function() {
            $('p').on('click', function() {
            var textBox = '<input type="text" class="textbox"/>';
            var a = $('<input>').attr("id","textBox"+idCount);
                $(textBoxDiv).append(a);
                idCount++;
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Click !</p>
        <div id="textBoxDiv" style="width:50%;height:50%">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer has already been accepted, but I dislike the option of using a global variable just to increment the count for the dynamically added id - when there is a cleaner way of doing it in the function using the length of the .textbox elements. Note that this will give a zero-indexed number for the id that is incremented each time the image is  clicked, because each time a textbox is appended - the length of the .textbox class increases by 1. I have put a console.log in there to demonstrate the increasing count:

```js
  $('.plusicon').on('click', function() {
    var textBox = '<input type="text" class="textbox"/>';
    var textboxLength = $('.textbox').length;
    $('#plusicondivbox').append(textBox);  
    $('.textbox:last').attr('id', 'id_' + textboxLength);
  console.log('id_' + textboxLength);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="plusicondiv" class="plusicon" src="vectorimages/pluseicon.svg" />

<div id="plusicondivbox" class="insidediv " style="margin-top:53px;"></div>
```